# SOAP request losing value in Integration Broker (PT8.52.14)

Tags: web-services, soap, peoplesoft

I've set up a **document** message in order to use it in a synchronous service operation. I've published this service, and I'm using [SOAPui](http://www.soapui.org/) and the built-in Service Operation Tester available directly through the PeopleTools>Integration Broker>Service Utilities>Service Operation Tester menu.

My issue : When I send a request filled with some values and then look at it in the synchronous service monitor, I don't see them any more. At some point, Integration Broker flushed the values out and I cannot figure out if this is a known bug, or something in my setup which could be wrong.

Note :

- Request and Response are the same message.
- Every field in the document has a length and a type set.
- No issue with a Non-Rowset based message
- I'm using Peopletools 8.52.14

My request is the following :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:nx="http://xmlns.oracle.com/Enterprise/Tools/schemas/NX_PAC.NX_IB_PERFS_EVENT.VERSION_2a">
   <soapenv:Header/>
 <soapenv:Body xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <NX_IB_PERFS_EVENT xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/Enterprise/Tools/schemas/NX_PAC.NX_IB_PERFS_EVENT.VERSION_2a">
      <EventName>XYZ</EventName>
      <PerfsDate>2015-02-09</PerfsDate>
      <AverageTiming>0.0</AverageTiming>
      <NumberOfExec>0.0</NumberOfExec>
      <AveragePost>0.0</AveragePost>
    </NX_IB_PERFS_EVENT>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The incoming values `EventName` and `PerfsDate` will disappear when looking at the original incoming message in the monitor. But this is not consistent since values show up after a reboot of the PIA.

Here's the PeopleCode of my Service Operation Handler :

```
method OnRequest
   /+ &_msg as Message +/
   /+ Returns Message +/
   /+ Extends/implements PS_PT:Integration:IRequestHandler.OnRequest +/
   &_msg.GetDocument().GetElement("PerfsDate").value = %Date;

   Return &_msg;
end-method;
```

I send back the request message, and just set up a date on tag `PerfsDate`.

In the Response message, `EventName`'s value is **empty**.

Any feedback about this ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you aren't properly retrieving values from the request message. Below is an example of how I would retrieve the values from an Integration Broker synchronous SOAP request:

```
method OnRequest
   /+ &_msg as Message +/
   /+ Returns Message +/
   /+ Extends/implements PS_PT:Integration:IRequestHandler.OnRequest +/

    Local XmlDoc &requestXmlDoc;
    Local XmlNode &requestRootNode;
    Local array of XmlNode &perfsDateNodes, &avgTimingNodes;
    Local string &perfsDateStr, &avgTimingStr;
    Local date &perfsDate;
    Local number &avgTiming;

    &requestXmlDoc = &_msg.GetXmlDoc();
    &requestRootNode = &requestXmlDoc.DocumentElement;

    &perfsDateNodes = &requestRootNode.GetElementsByTagName("PerfsDate");
    If &perfsDateNodes.Len > 0 Then
        &perfsDateStr = &perfsDateNodes[1].NodeValue;
        If IsDate(&perfsDateStr) Then
            &perfsDate = DateValue(&perfsDateStr);
        Else
            /* some error */ 
        End-If;
    Else
        /* some error */
    End-If;

     &avgTimingNodes = &requestRootNode.GetElementsByTagName("AverageTiming");
    If &avgTimingNodes.Len > 0 Then
        &avgTimingStr = &avgTimingNodes[1].NodeValue;
        If IsNumber(&avgTimingStr) Then
            &avgTiming = Value(&avgTimingStr)
        Else
            /* some error */  
        End-If;
    Else 
        /* some error */
    End-If;

    Return &This.CreateSOAPResponse(false, &avgTiming, &perfsDate, "No Error");

End-Method;
```

I would also create a separate method or class to create the response message.

For example:

```
/**
  * Create a SOAP response message based on the schema of the response   message
  *
  */
method CreateSOAPResponse
   /+ &hasError as Boolean, +/
   /+ &avgTiming as Number, +/
   /+ &perfsDate as Date, +/
   /+ &errorMessage as String +/
   /+ Returns Message +/
   Local SOAPDoc &responseSOAP;
   Local XmlDoc &responseXmlDoc;
   Local XmlNode &resultNode;
   Local Message &responseMessage;
   Local string &perfsDateStr, &avgTimingStr;

   If &hasError Then
      /* In the event of an error condition, certain response fields should be blank. */
      &avgTiming = "";
      &perfsDate = "";
   Else
      &errorMessage = "";
   End-If;

   /* Convert the number and date to string for response.*/
   If All(&avgTiming) Then
       &avgTimingStr = NumberToString("%*.*", &avgTiming);
   Else
      &avgTimingStr = "";
   End-If;

   If All(&perfsDate) Then
       &perfsDateStr = DateTimeToLocalizedString(&perfsDate, "yyyy-MM-dd");
   Else
      &perfsDateStr = "";
   End-If;
   &responseSOAP = CreateSOAPDoc();
   &responseSOAP.AddEnvelope(%SOAP_Schema);
   &responseSOAP.AddHeader();
   &responseSOAP.AddBody();
   &responseSOAP.AddMethod("SERVICE_OPERATION NAME", 0);

   &resultNode = &responseSOAP.MethodNode;
   &resultNode.AddAttribute("xmlns:tns", "NAMESPACE/RESPONSE_MESSAGE_NAME");

   &responseSOAP.AddParm("errorMessage", &errorMessage);
   &responseSOAP.AddParm("AverageTiming", &avgTimingStr);
   &responseSOAP.AddParm("PerfsDate", &perfsDateStr);

   &responseMessage = CreateMessage(Operation.OPERATION_NAME_HERE, %IntBroker_Response);
   &responseMessage.SetXmlDoc(&responseSOAP.XmlDoc);
   Return &responseMessage;
end-method;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This solution just won't work with document message. If you run it with such message , IB will send back "This method can only be used by nonrowset-based messages. (2,852)" , reffering to the GetXmlDoc();

Comment: I just now realized that you're doing rowset based messaging. My apologies - I should have read your question more carefully.

Comment: Instead of GetXmlDoc, you need to use GenXMLString() to create a string object containing the XML data. You can then parse the XML and see what is coming across in the message. I am not sure what is causing the problems you have described, but I imagine it is because you are treating the messages as if they were non-rowset based messages. You should be using record and rowset object types in there somewhere, as that is how you normally process them.

Comment: It's also not a Rowset-based message, but a Document Message, a new type introduced by Ptools 8.50. Document allow you to describe the structure of your data, and obtain a handy object to manipulate it easily... if only it would work :)